# Remove objects from a java set

Tags: java, set

How do i remove all the objects from one set, that exist also in an other set. for exaple:

```
SET 1 = { a,b,c,d,e,f)  |
                        |---> NEW SET 1= (a,b,d,e}
SET 2 = {c,f)           |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is

```
  set1.removeAll(set2);
```

Comment: Note that one will have to ensure that both the `equals` and `hashCode` implementations of the objects contained in the sets behave like they should, or it will not do what you want.

Comment: 100% agree. pretty straightforward :)

Answer (score 0):

code from org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils

```
  public static Collection subtract(final Collection a, final Collection b) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList( a );
        for (Iterator it = b.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            list.remove(it.next());
        }
        return list;
    }
```